# Saving files as .csv without losing decimal points

Tags: excel, csv, formatting, decimal

I am currently finding an issue when I am converting .xslx to .csv files with a piece of work I am currently completing. It is suppose to walk through from an initial value to a final value, with all the values in particular columns coming back to a difference of 0.

When in .xlsx there doesn't seem to be any issues with the walk through, as it comes back to 0. However, when I convert it to .csv it seems that the second decimal place seems to be removed and the first rounded for some of my larger values. This throws it out and it doesn't reconcile, when the csv is reopened.

I wondered if there was anything I could do to the CSV to stop this happening, as I am aware you can't save any formats, so it must be something in the .csv set up?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to multiply all your values by 1,000 or 10,000 or even 100,000.  That will shift the significant digits up so decimals are less likely to be dropped.

So, instead of storing .12345678 in a .CSV and potentially losing some of the decimal places, you'd be storing 123456.78 and be much less likely to lose any decimal places.

Would that work for you?

Comment: The values I am storing are already of that format, as we are only retaining two decimal places (accounting information), so I don't think this would help.